# TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined While rendering the react page server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have used these npm dependencies while rendering the react using node on server side.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
var request = require('request');
```

I can not use `componentDidMount` because it is never called while rendering server side. So, I used `componentWillMount` and my final code structure is like this :

```
var Content = React.createClass({
displayName: 'Content',
getInitialState: function getInitialState() {
    console.log('getInitialState');
    return {
        xyz : [],
        abc : ''
    };
},

componentWillMount: function componentWillMount() { 
    console.log('componentWillMount');  
    request(
        'some_url', 
        function (error, response, body) {
            console.log(response.statusCode);
         if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log('Request Call');
            this.setState = {
                    xyz : [],
                    abc : ''
           }
        } 
    }.bind(this));
},
render: function render() {
    console.log('render');
    return React.createElement(
        'div',
        { 
            className: 'clearfix container-fluid padding-none' },
            React.createElement(TopSection, { title: this.state.title, slug: this.state.slug })
       );
    }
});
```

My LifeCycle is going as follow

```
getInitialState
componentWillMount
render
Request Call
render
```

and after the render is called second time i got this error

```
Warning: React can't find the root component node for data-reactid
      value `.1va42hea328.1.0.1`. If you're seeing this message, it 
probably means that you've loaded two copies of React on the page. At   this
time, only a single copy of React can be loaded at a time.

/Users/me/Desktop/Projects/silly-poke/node_modules/react/lib/ReactMount.js:715

firstChildren[0] = deepestAncestor.firstChild;
                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined
```

Output of `npm ls` is as below :

```
     ├─┬ compression@1.6.2
│ ├─┬ accepts@1.3.3
│ │ ├─┬ mime-types@2.1.11
│ │ │ └── mime-db@1.23.0
│ │ └── negotiator@0.6.1
│ ├── bytes@2.3.0
│ ├─┬ compressible@2.0.8
│ │ └── mime-db@1.23.0
│ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│ │ └── ms@0.7.1
│ ├── on-headers@1.0.1
│ └── vary@1.1.0
├─┬ express@4.14.0
│ ├─┬ accepts@1.3.3
│ │ ├─┬ mime-types@2.1.11
│ │ │ └── mime-db@1.23.0
│ │ └── negotiator@0.6.1
│ ├── array-flatten@1.1.1
│ ├── content-disposition@0.5.1
│ ├── content-type@1.0.2
│ ├── cookie@0.3.1
│ ├── cookie-signature@1.0.6
│ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│ │ └── ms@0.7.1
│ ├── depd@1.1.0
│ ├── encodeurl@1.0.1
│ ├── escape-html@1.0.3
│ ├── etag@1.7.0
│ ├─┬ finalhandler@0.5.0
│ │ ├── statuses@1.3.0
│ │ └── unpipe@1.0.0
│ ├── fresh@0.3.0
│ ├── merge-descriptors@1.0.1
│ ├── methods@1.1.2
│ ├─┬ on-finished@2.3.0
│ │ └── ee-first@1.1.1
│ ├── parseurl@1.3.1
│ ├── path-to-regexp@0.1.7
│ ├─┬ proxy-addr@1.1.2
│ │ ├── forwarded@0.1.0
│ │ └── ipaddr.js@1.1.1
│ ├── qs@6.2.0
│ ├── range-parser@1.2.0
│ ├─┬ send@0.14.1
│ │ ├── destroy@1.0.4
│ │ ├─┬ http-errors@1.5.0
│ │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ │ └── setprototypeof@1.0.1
│ │ ├── mime@1.3.4
│ │ ├── ms@0.7.1
│ │ └── statuses@1.3.0
│ ├── serve-static@1.11.1
│ ├─┬ type-is@1.6.13
│ │ ├── media-typer@0.3.0
│ │ └─┬ mime-types@2.1.11
│ │   └── mime-db@1.23.0
│ ├── utils-merge@1.0.0
│ └── vary@1.1.0
├── parent-require@1.0.0
├─┬ react@0.14.8
│ ├─┬ envify@3.4.1
│ │ ├─┬ jstransform@11.0.3
│ │ │ ├── base62@1.1.1
│ │ │ ├─┬ commoner@0.10.4
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ commander@2.9.0
│ │ │ │ │ └── graceful-readlink@1.0.1
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ detective@4.3.1
│ │ │ │ │ ├── acorn@1.2.2
│ │ │ │ │ └── defined@1.0.0
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ glob@5.0.15
│ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ inflight@1.0.5
│ │ │ │ │ │ └── wrappy@1.0.2
│ │ │ │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ minimatch@3.0.2
│ │ │ │ │ │ └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.5
│ │ │ │ │ │   ├── balanced-match@0.4.1
│ │ │ │ │ │   └── concat-map@0.0.1
│ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ once@1.3.3
│ │ │ │ │ │ └── wrappy@1.0.2
│ │ │ │ │ └── path-is-absolute@1.0.0
│ │ │ │ ├── graceful-fs@4.1.4
│ │ │ │ ├── iconv-lite@0.4.13
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1
│ │ │ │ │ └── minimist@0.0.8
│ │ │ │ ├── private@0.1.6
│ │ │ │ ├── q@1.4.1
│ │ │ │ └─┬ recast@0.10.43
│ │ │ │   ├── ast-types@0.8.15
│ │ │ │   ├── esprima-fb@15001.1001.0-dev-harmony-fb
│ │ │ │   └── source-map@0.5.6
│ │ │ ├── esprima-fb@15001.1.0-dev-harmony-fb
│ │ │ ├── object-assign@2.1.1
│ │ │ └─┬ source-map@0.4.4
│ │ │   └── amdefine@1.0.0
│ │ └── through@2.3.8
│ └─┬ fbjs@0.6.1
│   ├── core-js@1.2.6
│   ├─┬ loose-envify@1.2.0
│   │ └── js-tokens@1.0.3
│   ├─┬ promise@7.1.1
│   │ └── asap@2.0.4
│   ├── ua-parser-js@0.7.10
│   └── whatwg-fetch@0.9.0
├── react-dom@0.14.8
└─┬ request@2.72.0
  ├── aws-sign2@0.6.0
  ├── aws4@1.4.1
  ├─┬ bl@1.1.2
  │ └─┬ readable-stream@2.0.6
  │   ├── core-util-is@1.0.2
  │   ├── inherits@2.0.1
  │   ├── isarray@1.0.0
  │   ├── process-nextick-args@1.0.7
  │   ├── string_decoder@0.10.31
  │   └── util-deprecate@1.0.2
  ├── caseless@0.11.0
  ├─┬ combined-stream@1.0.5
  │ └── delayed-stream@1.0.0
  ├── extend@3.0.0
  ├── forever-agent@0.6.1
  ├─┬ form-data@1.0.0-rc4
  │ └── async@1.5.2
  ├─┬ har-validator@2.0.6
  │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.3
  │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.2.1
  │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.5
  │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
  │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
  │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.1
  │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
  │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
  │ ├─┬ commander@2.9.0
  │ │ └── graceful-readlink@1.0.1
  │ ├─┬ is-my-json-valid@2.13.1
  │ │ ├── generate-function@2.0.0
  │ │ ├─┬ generate-object-property@1.2.0
  │ │ │ └── is-property@1.0.2
  │ │ ├── jsonpointer@2.0.0
  │ │ └── xtend@4.0.1
  │ └─┬ pinkie-promise@2.0.1
  │   └── pinkie@2.0.4
  ├─┬ hawk@3.1.3
  │ ├── boom@2.10.1
  │ ├── cryptiles@2.0.5
  │ ├── hoek@2.16.3
  │ └── sntp@1.0.9
  ├─┬ http-signature@1.1.1
  │ ├── assert-plus@0.2.0
  │ ├─┬ jsprim@1.3.0
  │ │ ├── extsprintf@1.0.2
  │ │ ├── json-schema@0.2.2
  │ │ └── verror@1.3.6
  │ └─┬ sshpk@1.8.3
  │   ├── asn1@0.2.3
  │   ├── assert-plus@1.0.0
  │   ├── dashdash@1.14.0
  │   ├── ecc-jsbn@0.1.1
  │   ├── getpass@0.1.6
  │   ├── jodid25519@1.0.2
  │   ├── jsbn@0.1.0
  │   └── tweetnacl@0.13.3
  ├── is-typedarray@1.0.0
  ├── isstream@0.1.2
  ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.1
  ├─┬ mime-types@2.1.11
  │ └── mime-db@1.23.0
  ├── node-uuid@1.4.7
  ├── oauth-sign@0.8.2
  ├── qs@6.1.0
  ├── stringstream@0.0.5
  ├── tough-cookie@2.2.2
  └── tunnel-agent@0.4.3
```

means  there is no other version of react loading as i have seen problem on searching this error.

Comment: value for  deepestAncestor?

Comment: did not get you !! How to get the value of deepestAncestor ?

Comment: If you can edit ReactMount.js:715, this line. add console.log(deepestAncestor), this will give some more clarity. Error looks deepestAncestor is undefined!!

Comment: yes its `undefined` ? any idea why ?

Comment: Thats the issue. From where you got deepestAncestor?  Try to get that

Comment: Its getting from reactId `    console.log(targetID);
    var deepestAncestor = findDeepestCachedAncestor(targetID) || ancestorNode;` which is `.nlit76u3nk.1.0.1` but it returns undefined

Comment: Can you post your HTML file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115743/discussion-between-chetan-wadhwa-and-saravanakumar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you are making a request inside componentWillMount. componentWillMount is called even for server side rendering so when this request comes back it'll try to setState on a component that doesn't exist (since server side rendering uses renderToString).

Move the request to componentDidMount so it only gets called on the client.

Additionally, if you'd still like to fetch data before rendering on the server then use something like redux-async-connect.